# GCM push to topics using PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write a PHP script that will send a push notification to my android app using the [topics method](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging). It seems to be successful and returns a message ID, but nothing will show up on the phone. I do have a similar python script, and that one works so GCM must have been implemented correctly in the app.

**Not working PHP script**

```
$msg = array(
    'to'          => '/topics/my_little_topic',
    'notifcation' => array(
                            'body'      => 'here is a message message',
                            'title'     => 'This is a title title',
                            'icon'      => "ic_launcher"
    )
);

$headers = array
(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: key='. API_ACCESS_KEY
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $msg, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;

?>
```

**Working python script**

```
from urllib2 import *
import urllib
import json
import sys

MY_API_KEY="AIzaSyBh...aWIVA"

messageTitle = sys.argv[1]
messageBody = sys.argv[2]

data={
    "to" : "/topics/my_little_topic",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : messageBody,
        "title" : messageTitle,
        "icon" : "ic_launcher"
    }
}

dataAsJSON = json.dumps(data)

print dataAsJSON

request = Request(
    "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
    dataAsJSON,
    { "Authorization" : "key="+MY_API_KEY,
      "Content-type" : "application/json"
    }
)

print urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: Are you positive that you're client app is properly subscribed to the corresponding topic?

Comment: @AL. Yes, I have a similar script but in python and that one works just fine, so definitely the app is subscribed to the topic. Right now, I'm just trying to convert what I had in python into php.

Comment: Odd. Are you also sending the same payload structure? Are you getting a successful response?

Comment: @AL. The payload is the same as far as I can tell (both have the same output when print). The php script gets successful responses with a unique message_id stub back from the API but nothing shows up in the app. I have posted the working python script just in case anyone want to take a look as well.

Comment: I'm unable to pinpoint anything out. Same payload but the other isn't received. There is definitely something amiss on the PHP side here, but the request is successful. Really weird. I'll take a look around other posts and compare the codes, maybe there's just something missing (I suggest you do the same too). I'll get back here if I find something.

Comment: @AL. Thank you for helping out, I have been debugging this almost all day today. I played around with different cURL options too but nothing seems to get it to work. Will keep on looking.

Comment: if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}   <<---  check for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I copied your whole PHP script and tested it on my end. My `onMessageReceived()` was being triggered, but I noticed that the details wasn't retrieved, same as your scenario.

It was simply missed. You misspelled `notifcation` in your script:

```
'notifcation' => array(
```

It's missing an `i`. It should be `notification`.

*Classic and easy to miss* (lol). Tried it on my end, was able to show a notification afterwards.

Comment: Aaaahhhhhh!!! I'm going to cry a bit now and then going to get that fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Lol. Cool. Good luck with your app. Cheers! :)