# Firebase push notification using PHP

Tags: php, android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase for push notifications. My PHP code is working fine. I'm getting success message, but not receiving the push notification in my Android app for single device and multi device. But using Firebase console for sending notification it's working fine. I got the notification on the Android device. Is there any server configuration that I need to add?

PHP Code:

```
$yourApiSecret = "AIzaSyDY";
$androidAppId = "traasasadad";
$data = array(
    "tokens" => "AAAA_kFbSQ4:APA91bQuMV-nRuTnVNFg0HD2C9PBnWWad",
    "notification" => "Hello World!"
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-Ionic-Application-Id: '.$androidAppId,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($yourApiSecret)
    )
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Android Code:

```
package com.seven77Trades.notification;

/**  * Created by ist on 21/3/17.  */ import
android.app.NotificationManager; import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import
android.media.RingtoneManager; import android.net.Uri; import
android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat; import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService; import
com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage; import
com.seven77Trades.HomeActivity; import com.seven77Trades.R;

public class FirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: 
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            /*Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getColor());
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getSound());
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag());
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction());*/


            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    } }
```

**Output:**

```
"{"multicast_id":8295856130292351869,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1492611205996022%0296efeff9fd7ecd"}]}"
```

Comment: Does your notification data need an `alert` field?  [This documentation](http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-sending-push) seems to indicate it does.

Comment: Also see examples here: http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-api-examples

Comment: Why not just send directly with FCM (`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`)?

Comment: @AL I'm  already use this URL , and i got success message but not receive in android app. Is there any Sever white listing

Comment: AFAIK, there is no server whitelisting in FCM. Could you post you're Android side code?

Comment: @Al I'm added my Android code

Comment: Thanks. Code looks fine. Could you try using the FCM endpoint, while using [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43357488/4625829) as reference for the PHP code?

Comment: @Al  I'm refer your post and  i was using same code and its return me success message id .When  I'm using fire base console  for sending notification using notification tab then I'm receiving notification in my android app.  What's  wrong with code i don't understand .

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution .finally I'm receiving notification in android device.When we are sending notification using API (php,java,python) that time android application getting this request in different method (**WakefulBroadcastReceiver**) and when we sending  using fire base console then request comes different method (**FirebaseMessagingService**).

Here the BrackPullBroadCastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
GcmIntentService.class.getName());

// Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}




public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

private Context context;

public GcmIntentService() {
super("GcmIntentService");
}

String imageUrl = "";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

context = this;
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
for (String key: extras.keySet())
{
Log.d (TAG, key + " is a key in the bundle");
Log.d(TAG, extras.get(key) + "");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some mistake with the target url you can try sending the notification like this:

```
$url = 'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

      $fields =array(
        "notification"=> array(
                       "title" => 'sometitle',
                       "body" => $message, //Can be any message you want to send
                       "icon" => $image,
                       "click_action" => "http://google.com"

                       ),
                   "registration_ids"=> 'Your android app fcm token',
                   "data"=> array(
                     "data" => "something",
                   )
               );

      $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
      $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "your firebase app key",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
      );

      $ch = curl_init ();
      curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
      curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
      curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
      curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

      $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
      curl_close ( $ch );
```

Also you can pass custom data in the payload